# Storing a huge amount of data as a cookie

Tags: http, cookies, http-headers, storage

I'm trying to store a huge amount of data on a user's machine (this is the safest way to do this) that is transferred from my server. The data is about 4K - I've tried storing it as a cookie but I get a 500 error because it is too big. I tried chunking it but the amount of space it uses in the headers is too big. Currently I send back an identifier and store the data on my server to be retrieved using that ID, but that's less secure than I'd like it to be. Does anyone have any other ideas on how I can accomplish this? I mean, if what I'm doing now is really the best way then that's the way I'll do it - but it would be nice to not have to store this data on my server.

Comment: Have you seen http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html?

Comment: Why would it be less safe to store it on the server? And what do you need the data for?

Comment: You can get security by encrypting the data with a key that the client has, and storing only the encrypted data on the server. (Of course, implementing crypto properly is not easy.)

Comment: @katrielalex That's not a bad idea, thanks for this!